# Batch extract multiple pass protected .7z

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I'd like to write a PowerShell script to extract multiple password-protected .7z files, that have their passwords saved inside a text file that its filename contains the name of the .7z

File structure example:

EncryptedFile1_02192020.7z

EncryptedFile1_password.txt

EncryptedFile2_02192020.7z

EncryptedFile2_password.txt

The script below works only if there are 1 .7z and 1 .txt file in the folder.

```
$pass = get-content *.txt
7z.exe x *.7z -p"$pass" -o*
```

Problem: I do not know how to use the combination of foreach and -Like statements to batch extract multiple encrypted files in the working directory. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A Google search for `ForEach Get-ChildItem` returns [This Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568221/using-foreach-with-get-childitem-recurse) which should help you.  Just ignore the -Recurse suggestion if all your files are in one subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one method. It gathers the files inside the rootfolder, groups them on the first part of the filename before the underscore `_` and finds the files ending in `.txt` and `.7z` inside these groups.
If we have both, the password is read from the text file and the 7z file is extracted.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'TheFolderWhereTheFilesAre' -File | 
    Group-Object @{Expression = {($_.Name -split '_')[0]}} |
    Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $pwFile = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.txt' }
        $7zFile = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.7z' }
        if (($pwFile) -and ($7zFile)) {
            Write-Host "Extracting file '$($7zFile.FullName)'"
            # the single quotes are needed when the password contains spaces or special characters
            $pass = "'{0}'" -f (Get-Content -Path $pwFile.FullName -Raw)
            7z.exe x $($7zFile.FullName) -p"$pass" -o* 
    }
}
```

<sup>Note, If the files all start with `EncryptedFile_`, then you can add `-Filter 'EncryptedFile_*.*'` to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet to speed things up</sup>